# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'cookies'

Tags: python, django

I am making a webpage. There are two views. `Index` and `Detail`.
In index I setup the cookie for user using `response.set_cookie('key', key)` where `response = HttpResponseRedirect(file_url)`. In `detail` function when I try to get data from cookie using

```
   if 'key' not in request.cookies:
      key = request.COOKIES['key']
```

I am getting error: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'cookies'`. 
Detailed error link : http://dpaste.com/1P017V6

Please help me!.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You typed `request.cookies`, but `cookies` must be upper case. Try with this:

```
if 'key' not in request.COOKIES:
```